# Django:how to render template and send context to template with ajax?

Tags: python, django, ajax

(sorry for my bad English)

Hello. I know partly how ajax is used with Django. but I have some problems. Some of them are: how to render a template with ajax? How to send Django to template with ajax? I searched the internet but I couldn't find exactly what I wanted.
I would be glad if you could also recommend a detailed resource on the use of ajax and Django. (free:( ).please help me guy.thanks now.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create instances in your Django's views.py file which returns the data you wanna display in template.
Then you need to create an ajax function inside the template. Here is a basic ajax function that can be modified to your needs:

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get.asp", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

What it does is reach out to the source of data in your case it will probably be the instances in views.py. "readyState == 4" tells you the data load is complete, while "this.status == 200" tells you if the request is successful.

The question on how to display the data depends on you and the type of data.

Comment: Thanks man. How will the views part of this ajax be? I'll be glad if you throw it in that part. As for the data sending part, I want to send a context (with ajax) .for example:

Comment: ```    context = {
        'form':form,
        'title':'title',
        'btntext':'text',
    }
```

Comment: There is no views.py for the provided ajax as it is a basic ajax for understanding. So your context is a python dict. It depends on how you want to display it. It would be great if you could include your existing codes into the question. I don't think I can go more in detail which such amount of information